# RXJS, What's the difference between Observable.create and new Observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

In a template, I set an async pipe for a Observable with.

```
*ngFor="let checkIn of checkIns | async"
```

In the component, `this.checkIns = this.service.getCheckIns()`.

In the service, I got:

```
getCheckIns(): Observable<any> {
  return new Observable((observer) => {
    observer.next(...)
  }
}
```

I notice if I swap out `new Observable()` with `Observable.create()`, there's no difference:

```
getCheckIns(): Observable<any> {
  return Observable.create((observer) => {
    observer.next(...)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct, these two are synonymous.

See source code: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Observable.ts#L56

The static method `Observable.create(...)` just calls `new Observable(...)` under the hood.